# Can someone explain the meaning of writing code like this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I saw original angularjs code and there are many functions defined like this

```
this.$get = function() {
    return function ngParamSerializer(params) {
        // some content...
    };
}
```

I have no idea what for... and why is it needed. a function that return a function? will it not return the result of the inner function?

Why not just write?

```
this.$get = function() {
    // some content...
}
```

Example:

```
this.$get = function() {
    return function ngParamSerializer(params) {
         return "Hello World"
    };
}
```

Isn't it the same as

```
this.$get = function() {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

Will you not get "Hello World" when you call the this.$get() ??

Comment: I don't know why, but I do know that they are not the same. When you call `this.$get()` you will get a function that returns "Hello world". You have to call that function again to get to the actual string.

Comment: In the first snippet, you'll have to call it like `this.$get()()`

Comment: but whats the point? what for?

Comment: does it only return a function or is there something else done in `$get`?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions This may help!

Comment: In fact, if you want the result is a function, it should be a function. That's all. Everything else is: what's the result?

Comment: @SDhaliwal postet a nice blog post explaining a usecase, but it only makes sense if (in your case) the `$get` function would actually accept some params (or pass arguments on to the returning function) otherwise it seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It could be helpful when the inner function is called not by you, but you want to provide some parameters into this function.

I don't know how `$get` function from your example is used by angular, so I'll provide an example from node.js [express](http://expressjs.com) module. There is the concept of *middleware*. Middleware is a function which accepts three parameters `req`, `res`, `next` and calls `next` function with/without error parameter to stop/continue processing. Middlewares are called by express in the order of declaration.

In the example below, I want to define a route and add authentication logic to restrict access to the resource. As you see `auth` accepts `userRole` parameter, and uses it when `middleware` is called by express:

```
app.get('/user/:id', auth('admin'), getUser);

let auth = function(userRole) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (userRole === 'admin') {
      return next();
    }
    return next(new Error('Auth error'));
  };
}
```

Comment: if `angular` would call `getData` in a hook, that doesn't mean it would call `getDataWrapper` with a param before. I don't understand your answer, tbh.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example from real world.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript functions are real citizens. You could assign functions to vars.

```
var f = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var f2 = f;

console.log (f(1,2)); // -> 3
console.log (f2(4,5)); // -> 9
```

The sense of the first example is to return a function which will be called by the caller. this is a kind of callback

In your case, you can ask $get for a function which you can call later with your parameters

```
  var n = this.$get();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
     ...
     n(i, i*i);   // call function, e.g. notify others.
     ...
  }
```

returning directly the result of n is obviously not the same because this would not allow to pass parameters.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you probably saw this in the code of a Provider.

They mostly look like this:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider('globalsetting', function () {
        this.$get = function () {
            var appname = "Lawyer App";
            return {
                appName: appname
            };
        }
    })
});
```

which then can be used like this:

```
app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, globalsetting) {
    $scope.name = globalsetting.appName;
});
```

*(example borrowed from the [Infragistics blog](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/02/23/what-is-a-provider-in-angularjs.aspx))*

Now imagine that this code is a bit more complex, and you want your service to be reusable, but to vary slightly between applications. Like this:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider('globalsetting', function () {
        this.$get = function (appAudience) {
            var appname = appAudience + " App";
            return {
                appName: appname
            };
        }
    })
});
```

But as you can see in the usage example, `$get` will be called by the framework, not you, so you can't directly pass parameters to it. So one thing you can do is to return a function (which *can* have parameters, unlike `$get`), not a fixed value:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider('globalsetting', function () {
        this.$get = function () {
            return {
                getAppName: function (appAudience) {
                    return appAudience + " App";
                }
            };
        }
    })
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, globalsetting) {
    $scope.name = globalsetting.getAppName("Lawyer");
    //$scope.name is now "Lawyer App"
});
```

Seeing that your example code returns a function with params, I'd guess this is the reason in your case too. Note that, however, there are [more sophisticated ways for doing this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe).